# Discord bot hosted on Heroku offline

Tags: heroku, discord

My Discord bot suddenly went offline at some point between yesterday and today. It is hosted on Heroku, and it is not sleeping, since it is a worker dyno and not a web dyno. Please see the code from the Heroku logs that appear to be repeating over and over again.

```
2019-07-09T17:43:33.696189+00:00 app[worker.1]: -1 17:43:33 ShardsCoordinator | Starting NadekoBot v2.29.8
2019-07-09T17:42:09+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-globular-19760 sample#active-connections=5 sample#load-avg-1m=0.03 sample#load-avg-5m=0.03 sample#load-avg-15m=0.035 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664220kB sample#memory-free=13386396kB sample#memory-cached=889180kB sample#memory-redis=5365936bytes sample#hit-rate=0.96191 sample#evicted-keys=0
2019-07-09T17:43:37.024954+00:00 app[worker.1]: -1 17:43:37 ShardsCoordinator | Images are already present in redis. Use .imagesreload to force update if needed.
2019-07-09T17:43:55.415873+00:00 app[worker.1]: 0 17:43:55 NadekoBot | Shard 0 logging in ...
2019-07-09T17:43:56.383524+00:00 app[worker.1]: 0 17:43:56 NadekoBot | Rest | Rate limit triggered: voice/regions
2019-07-09T17:44:19.290316+00:00 app[worker.1]: 0 17:44:19 NadekoBot | Rest | Rate limit triggered: voice/regions
2019-07-09T17:44:19.490406+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604078+00:00 app[worker.1]: Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604093+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.EnterAsync(Int32 id, RestRequest request)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604095+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604097+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604100+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync(String method, String endpoint, RestRequest request)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604107+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendAsync[TResponse](String method, String endpoint, String bucketId, ClientBucketType clientBucket, RequestOptions options)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604109+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.GetVoiceRegionsAsync(RequestOptions options)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604111+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.OnLoginAsync(TokenType tokenType, String token)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604114+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Rest.BaseDiscordClient.LoginInternalAsync(TokenType tokenType, String token, Boolean validateToken)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604117+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Rest.BaseDiscordClient.LoginInternalAsync(TokenType tokenType, String token, Boolean validateToken)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604119+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at Discord.Rest.BaseDiscordClient.LoginAsync(TokenType tokenType, String token, Boolean validateToken)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604122+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at NadekoBot.NadekoBot.LoginAsync(String token) in C:\Users\Kuro\source\repos\NadekoBot\NadekoBot.Core\Services\NadekoBot.cs:line 266
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604124+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at NadekoBot.NadekoBot.RunAsync() in C:\Users\Kuro\source\repos\NadekoBot\NadekoBot.Core\Services\NadekoBot.cs:line 301
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604126+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at NadekoBot.NadekoBot.RunAndBlockAsync() in C:\Users\Kuro\source\repos\NadekoBot\NadekoBot.Core\Services\NadekoBot.cs:line 358
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604128+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at NadekoBot.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Kuro\source\repos\NadekoBot\src\NadekoBot\Program.cs:line 24
2019-07-09T17:44:19.604199+00:00 app[worker.1]:    at NadekoBot.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
2019-07-09T17:44:19.672681+00:00 app[worker.1]: run.sh: line 8: 32580 Aborted                 dotnet NadekoBot.dll
```

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to figure it out?